# Making an image / div fade with CSS3, without using a hover

Tags: animation, css, opacity, transition

I have a div with an image in it. At the moment I use CSS3 animation to fade it off, but the performance is terrible.

I am pretty sure I should be using transitions. Problem is I cannot find one example that isn't triggered by a hover.

How can I make it so that when the page is loaded, after a delay of 2 seconds, the image/div fades in from 0%?

At the moment, as I said with animation, I have:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadetime {
from {
 opacity: 0;
}

50% {
 opacity: 0;
}

to {
 opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You could use a transition in a class, and then add the class with css after 2 seconds.

Answer (score 12):

```
@-webkit-keyframes FadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}

.object {
    -webkit-animation-name: FadeIn;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
}
```

Comment: Hi, is it easy to adapt this to create an image gallery, how would you go about fadeOut the first layer to reveal the second and then the second layer to reveal the third etc. Thanks Gary

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery is probably a better way to go:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#mainContent').hide();
$('#mainContent').delay(2000).fadeIn(500);

});

</script>
```

Where #mainContent is the div you want to fade in

Comment: Jquery is MUCH laggier than CSS3 animations.

Comment: jQuery is good as a fallback (using Modernizr to detect CSS animation support), however CSS3 animations are far quicker and likely the way to go in the near future